# Regex specific dash pattern (Python)

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers, character

I am trying to make a regex that recognizes a specific dash-pattern in a string.

String example: `1L34-1A345-12B45-1a or 01aB-5432A-0014z-20`

Explained: four character - five characters - five characters - two characters

The string contains numbers, upper- and lowercase characters.

I came up with the following pattern and it does the trick, but I think it could be expressed a bit simpler.

```
pattern = '[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can simplify your regex to e.g.

```
pattern = r'[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: you can even simplify store this `[A-Za-z0-9]` in a variable and use varible to create regex

Comment: @Stefan Super! Just what I was looking for. And deadshot, good idea with the variable! Have a nice day! Thanks